# Replace Windows 10 login screen

Tags: windows-authentication

I would like to find out if it is possible to replace your windows login screen with an alternative authentication service.

For example. I have a google account. I would like to sign in with my google account to my notebook instead of using my windows credentials, and subsequently my wifi. I probably would need to pair my windows UPN with the google credentials so that after my account has been authenticated, my "service" will then do an automatic login with my windows account.

If somebody can help me in the right direction of what to look at and if it is at all possible, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Counter-question: why can't you use your Google account to log in to your iPhone/different mailservice/[random web-account]? Because they don't **want** to use oauth/google/whatever.

Comment: I didn't ask why you can't. But if it is possible. Your comment is not constructive at all

Comment: Sorry if you misunderstood me: no you can't.

Comment: @Lennie is right. Additionally to 'no you can't' he tried to explain 'why you can't'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup LDAP on a Linux server, create an active directory domain and let it authenticate users via Google's API. Then you connect your Windows machine to your Linux AD.